# How to solve laptop GPU overheating problem in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, overheating

### Module

Thinkpad W540. Spec: intel core i7 4800mq, Nvidia Quadra K2100M.

### Problem:

I tried fresh installs of Ubuntu16.04, Kubuntu16.04, Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, and all of them suffer from the problem of Nvidia gpu overheating. The battery life is only about half of what I used to have running Ubuntu14.04 or Windows10, also my left palm feels uncomfortably hot when typing, because Nvidia GPU just locates beneath that position.

### Failed attempts in solving this problem:

1, Install bumblebee to block Nvidia in daily use. I used to run bumblebee under Ubuntu14.04, and it worked fine. But it seems that bumblebee is unable to block Nvidia under 16.04.

2, Install Nvidia drivers and switch to Intel GPU using Nvidia-prime.
following [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481540/550697):
Blacklist Nouveau and press ctr+alt+F1, then login and

```
service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 # I've also tried nvidia-361. 
sudo prime-select intel
```

These commands are executed successfully, but the laptop gpu is still overheating.

3, Put nouveau into blacklist, or uninstall nouveau by

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

And after rebooting the system, the return of " lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2 " is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

This is strange since nouveau has already been removed, and the overheating problem is still there.

I'm still struggling with this issue, and I do not need to use Nvidia card under ubuntu, so disable it under Ubuntu will be enough. Can someone help to solve? Many thanks to your kind replies.

Comment: I've tried Ubuntu14.04, with the linux kernel 4.2.0-38, The GPU seems to also overheat and bumblebee fails too. So this problem may not be specific to only Ubuntu16.04. But I'm not sure about how other linux distros behave with new linux kernels.

Comment: Follow the link...This might help.
Found TLP helpful...
[Fix Overheating](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/)