# X will not start after upgrade. Number of monitors does not match number detected

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, xorg, multiple-monitors

Last night I upgraded to 16.04 LTS. Upon trying to Log in I kept resetting.

Went to  terminal screen an log on. If I try `startx` then I get little in the way of useful info.

`/var/log/Xorg.2.log` does not have any obvious error messages I can see.

Running `X :1 -configure` returns the error:

```
(++) Using config file : "/ome/userName/xorg.conf.new"
(++) Using the systemconfig directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg/conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected screens.
```

I have dual monitors installed on a Nvidia GeForce GT430. I look at `/home/userName/xorg.conf.new` and I can see two monitors set up.

`lsmod | grep nvidia` shows a Nvidia module is installed.

I've tried reinstalling binary drivers after being told:

> The distribution provided pr-install script failed! Continue
>   installation anyway?

When selecting `Yes`. I get the error:

> The kernel header file /lib/modules/4.4.0-45- generic/build/include/linux/version.h does not exist.

Despite making sure sources are installed but sure enough versions.h does not exist in this dir.

Any ideas?

Comment: "version.h" doesn't exist in my `/lib/modules/4.4.0-45- generic/build/include/linux/` directory either. I suspect your Nvidia installation script is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Newer driver script sorted the issue and on to new problems! The joys of updating.

Comment: You bet. Do you want to answer your own question and mark it solved to take your question out of unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0):

WinEunuuch2Unix had it. Turned out I was running an old driver install script. Downloaded the latest from the nvidia website and the script ran correctly.

In the process of messing around I had also installed nouveau along the way that caused some conflicts. This needed to be uninstalled and disabled which I did as per this question.

[Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau)