# NVidia 1080ti install on Ubuntu 16.04.2 - what does it mean if card doesn't appear under Additional Drivers?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, additional-drivers

I am trying to install the nVidia 378.13 drivers for a GEForce 1080ti on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.2 64 bit.

I installed the drivers using ppa (using the technique [described here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/how-to-install-nvidia-375-39-378-13-via-ppa-in-ubuntu/)). I blacklisted nouveau (using the technique [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau)).

However, my NVidia card does not show up under "Additional Drivers." As in, there is no top-level graphics card there at all, just my AMD processor, which has two radiobuttons I can use to select the proprietary AMD driver.

Under System Settings > Details > Graphics it says Graphics Device/PCIe/SSE2

When I do:

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
```

I get

```
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

Can anyone give me any insight into how to get this NVidia card installed? I want to use CUDA so, as far as I understand, it's important that I use the NVidia drivers.

Comment: `driver=nvidia` means it's installed.

Comment: What does it mean if the card isn't listed under "Additional Drivers"?

Comment: Probably nothing but it should appear there after adding the PPA and `sudo apt update`. Please edit your question and describe exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing. Evidently the Nvidia driver in question (378.13) is not supported on 16.04.02. See this from Nvidia support:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1000169/linux/378-13-driver-is-not-compatible-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts-linux-4-8-kernel-based-/

The solution he found was to go back to 16.04.01. That is obviously not doable if the 16.04.01 distro is not available from Ubuntu.  Can it be gotten somewhere? Surely there's an archive repository of Ubuntu distributions.

Comment: You just need to go to the Ubuntu old-releases: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/

Comment: anonymous2 - That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!