# Ubuntu gnome 17.04 stuck on light blue screen after install

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 17.04

I just installed ubuntu gnome 17.04 on a brand new build. Once install completed I clicked to restart as it asked in the wizard, then when it tried to start the Ubuntu OS I get this blue screen shown in the image:

[blue screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reDjR.jpg)

If I leave the screen it will go black for a few seconds and then appear blue again. I've read that it might be my video card drivers that might be a problem? I have an nvidia gtx 1080ti. I tried getting into the shell with various commands I've seen on other similar question threads but theres no response from the screen. Nothing works. What could this be ? Huge thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau