# Dual screen stretching with nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop with a nvidia card and an integrated intel card, and a HDMI screen connected to it. I understand PRIME support has been problematic in the past, but the newer nvidia drivers are quite good. I'm using driver version 375.66.

I can use either screens fine, or both with mirroring, but trying to use both as independent screens results in this strange stretching:

[image]

Both screens are 1920x1080. As can be seen in the screenshot, some GUI elements (e.g. unity-panel) are scaled correctly to a single screen, while most others (e.g. windows) are stretched through both screens. Interestingly, nvidia's applet does not detect both monitors, while ubuntu's display applet does, as can be seen in the screenshot.

This is my `xorg.conf` (although I'm not sure if the nvidia driver even uses it at all):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this out -

According to NVIDIA, it's because the built in display is connected to intel iGPU. ( source: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/807239/nvidia-server-setting-utility-doesn-t-see-laptop-screen/)

Which basically means that Nvidia x server has no control over your built in display.

To solve this, switch graphic mode from **MShybrid** to **discrete** in BIOS setting, which can force the built in monitor to be driven by you discrete GPU, and x server will work correctly to recognize both built in and external display.

Comment: Unfortunately my BIOS doesn't have that option. I could try updating it, since the laptop is quite old (late 2012), but I would rather avoid flashing if I can.

Comment: Also, you can force discrete-only through nvidia's x server settings app (which I did already).

Comment: And did that solve the problem?

Comment: No, I was using that setting already, prior to opening this question.