# Can't switch to NVidia graphics card on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I would like to switch to NVidia Geforce 740m instead of Intel Ivybridge Mobile. I've tried multiple solutions found on askubuntu but nothing seems to work.

Updating drivers, installing prime, removing all NVidia drivers and installing them again + prime - been there done that

Still when I enter NVidia X Server Settings, PRIME profiles are unavailable. Switching through terminal using prime-select nvidia doesn't give any results as well.

Below lspci output:

```
    ~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK107M [GeForce GT 740M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

lshw gives me that:

```
    ~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 740M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I guess configuration entry shouldn't be empty in NVidia info but don't know what to do with that.

[This is how my Additional Drivers tab looks like on Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laEiS.png) and finally the
[NVidia X Server Settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVg8v.png). As you can see the PRIME profiles are unavailable. Even though it's installed

```
~$ whereis nvidia-prime
nvidia-prime: /usr/share/nvidia-prime
```

Any ideas? I really stuck on this, would be greatful for any help.

Comment: You should probably stick with Intel. It's there for a reason. Use bumblebee or prime to use Nvidia for gaming instead.

Comment: Do you have any (leftover) "blacklist nvidia-375" lines in any file in the /etc/modprobe.d directory?

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` Did you ever install `bumblebee`?, If so make sure it & `primus` are removed.  Or just run `sudo apt  purge  nvidia* bumblebee primus` When done reboot then `sudo apt install nvidia-375`  When done reboot & see what's up.

Comment: No sign of nvidia on the blacklist. I've followed @doug guide and it goes only to login screen, after entering the password it shows weirdly aligned wallpaper for a monent and then goes back to login screen.

Comment: I used this guide (works for other than dell laptops obviously)
http://www.dell.com/support/article/dk/da/dkbsdt1/sln298431/a-guide-to-nvidia-optimus-on-dell-pcs-with-an-ubuntu-operating-system?lang=en works with nvidia-375 and prime-indicator

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau/481540#481540

Comment: NAA from @Kadett87 converted to comment: 

I used [this guide](http://www.dell.com/support/article/dk/da/dkbsdt1/sln298431/a-guide-to-nvidia-optimus-on-dell-pcs-with-an-ubuntu-operating-system?lang=en) (works for other than dell laptops obviously) 

works with nvidia-375 and prime-indicator

Comment: It is suddenly working but unfortunately I can't tell exactly what I did. I followed Kadett87 guide but it wasn't working. Then I tried to install drivers manually like in related question which @Elder Geek provided. This resulted that I couldn't even log in into system. So I've removed all nvidia stuff and installed all drivers using apt-get same as before. Now I can switch through PRIME profiles. I would really like to know why because right now it looks like magic

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've decided to write down what I did to make this working. Maybe someone will find this useful. I'm not sure which step got PRIME profiles working so I'll just put here all steps I've made.

## 1. Blacklist all unwanted drivers:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

blacklist amd76x_edac #this might not be required for x86 32 bit users.
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

## 2. Reinstall drivers and prime:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1 bumblebee* nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

reboot
```

Note: for some people this is enough what they need to do, so check if PRIME profiles are working before going to next step

## 3. Try to install nvidia driver manually

Download wanted driver version from nvidia site (I've chosen same version of driver as apt-get nividia-current downloaded).

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

Stop display manger, in my case that was:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Run install package:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-<version>.run
```

For all installation wizard question response yes (it's not part of this guide which I am proud of)

```
sudo update-initramfs -u

reboot
```

In my case I couldn't even boot system after that but this might work so check again if PRIME profiles are available after this steps.

If you are not able to boot as me, CTRL + ALT + F1 and repeat step 2. PRIME profile should be available after that.