# Nvidia driver stopped working; having trouble reinstalling drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg.conf

Recently I did some updates and when I restarted, my display stayed blank. I figured it was because the update so I switched my monitor over to the motherboard's port. I'm currently using integrated graphics to troubleshoot this issue.

```
glxinfo | grep -i vendor
```

shows Mesa Project and SGI and Intel open source.

When I checked the driver manager, it said the Nvidia drivers were installed and being used, but when I ran `nvidia-smi`, no output showed. I first tried reinstalling the Nvidia drivers by doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and rebooting, but `nvidia-smi` still displays nothing.

Then I [tried blacklisting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau) the open source drivers which it may have defaulted to. In that process, I noticed there was no xorg.conf file where it should have been, only xorg.conf.backup and xorg.conf.failsafe, etc. So I ran

```
cp xorg.conf.backup xorg.conf
```

and that only made matters worse - on boot it wasn't able to detect display settings and some menu came up about configuration but my mouse/keyboard stopped working. I mounted the filesystem and reverted the changes I made, so that's where I'm at now.

Something is goofy here, because `lsmod | grep nouveau` returns some lines (video, wmi, drm, ttm, ...) but nvidia still shows nothing.

doing:

```
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

gives a list of modules - glx, intel, modesetting, fbdev, vesa, fbdevhw,...

How do I get my system to recognize the correct Nvidia drivers and fix my xorg.conf?

update; grep "EE\|WW" /var/log/Xorg.0.log gives this:

> (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.

I think it has something to do with installing ubuntu-desktop at some point...