# How do I install Ubuntu on MSI GS63VR laptop with GTX 1070 (Max-Q)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, msi

I recently got an MSI GS63VR 7RG with GTX 1070 (Max-Q). It came preinstalled with Windows 10. When I tried to install Ubuntu 17.10 alongside Windows from a USB drive, it went to blackscreen showing some nouveau error. I tried disabling the card from BIOS but I couldn't find any option. Is there any way I can install Ubuntu on my system (without screwing my Windows installation up)? I am stuck on this for the last 4 days! Any help will be much appreciated!

Edit: It is different from the [Install Nvidia driver instead of nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau) fix since I do not get to go to the shell itself, let alone blacklisting some driver.

I fixed it by adding nouveau.modeset=0 in the grub (by pressing e and appending the same after "..quiet no splash..".

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi, I had checked the solution there. Unfortunately, it does not apply for me. I do not have any preinstalled Ubuntu, I am trying to install ubuntu alongside windows from flash drive without any way to install required driver packages during the installation (since it gives me a black-screen).

Comment: Still seems like the correct answer to me because you're getting a nouveau error. Your dual-boot is irrelevant. In grub, select a recovery console so you avoid the black screen.

Comment: Does it have nVidia G-Sync?

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix: No, it does not.

Comment: user535733: Please refer to my edit of the original question. Thanks a lot anyways! It is much appreciated!

Comment: How did you fix it permanently? The edit you made would only be effective for the current boot. It would be helpful if you removed your solution from the question, and posted it as an answer instead - that's how the site works, hopefully :)