# No integrated graphics, blacklisted nouveau, new graphics card not recognized, can't boot at all anymore

Tags: nouveau

While trying to replace an old graphics card with a new one from Nvidia I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022029/ubuntu-16-04-wont-use-nvidia-drivers-gpu-not-detected) and blacklisted Nouveau since only the old card was being recognized via that. Unfortunately now I can no longer boot at all since it seems no card is recognized at all anymore. The motherboard just beeps 5 times about a minute after powering up and all I see is a black screen.

What are my options now? I can't figure out how to access the machine at all at this point.

Comment: Please add output of this command `sudo lshw -c video`.

Comment: I would love to, but I only see a black screen - any suggestions how I could enter that and see the output?

Comment: Blacklisting `nouveau` is always a bad idea. It is fallback, if proprietary drivers don't load. But it seems that you didn't install the new card properly. Can you reach BIOS or grub menu? If not, it's not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I've been trying to reach the BIOS - pressing ESC, F1, F2, F8, or F12 after startup (not sure which one is correct for this machine) but none seem to get me anywhere. Should getting to BIOS work without nouveau?

Comment: That means (MB beeps) that it is a hardware problem. The card is not inserted properly, power is not connected, MB doesn't support this card, etc. Unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: More of a question for serverfault then?

Comment: Maybe this might help for your beeps from your motherboard:  https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm