# Help with installing cgmanager in 17.10

Tags: 17.10

When trying to run Heroes of Newerth on 17.10 I got missing dependency:

```
./hon-x86_64: error while loading shared libraries: libcgmanager.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked it up and I found that 17.10 doesn't include this packaged. I tried installing it manually from '16.04' but it's missing dependencies. What would be best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `libcgmanager0` from here making sure you pick the right architecture:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libcgmanager0

Install it using the `apt` command:

`sudo apt install ./libcgmanager0_`... (press TAB to auto complete)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: My dear friend, I am not confusing anything with anything. I am on artful (17.10). Yes the package is from xenial (16.04). By following the instructions in my answer I was able to install it and have the program that needed it running on artful. The OP must have done something wrong

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you! I apologize for any confusion I may have experienced when reading your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`libcgmanager.so` was included in the [libcgmanager-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libcgmanager-dev) package for which the last version available that I could find was for Zesty which might still be available [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libcgmanager-dev) but will likely be moved as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) if it hasn't been already.

**If you aren't a developer and don't actually enjoy running down bugs,** I would urge you to stick with LongTermSupport releases which IMHO receive better support.

17.10 will fall out of support in July of 2018 whereas 14.04 LTS will be supported until April 2019 and 16.04 LTS will be supported until April of 2021. (both of those aforementioned LTS releases have the libcgmanager-dev package containing the file you need (and any dependencies). The [next LTS release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) will be Bionic Beaver in April of 2018. If you have an overriding reason to maintain 17.10 you might consider dual booting an LTS release so that you have an easy alternative solution when a short term release is missing a package you are depending on.

The only other alternative I can think of is to rely on an "untrusted PPA" such as [ubuntu-lxc](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=artful)

```
This PPA contains the latest stable release of:
 - CGManager
 - LXC
 - LXCFS
 - LXD

As well as any required dependencies of the above.
```

Caveat: Note that this PPA will roll to new major versions whenever they are released. If you need more long term stability, consider using the [lts PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/lts) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't mind 17.10 instability as I will be using it only to play the game. I wukl

Comment: Sorry I sent my reply to fast... I wanted to say that because of it I will first try your suggestion about ubuntu-lxc if this doesn't work than I perhaps switch back to 16.04.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? I don't see libcgmanager-dev in either stable or lts PPAs listed in the answer. Plus you don't need the -dev package, all you need is libcgmanager0.

Comment: @InnocentBystander based on your answer below you appear to be confusing Xenial (16.04) with 17.10 which is what this question is about.

Comment: @ElderGeek please see my comment below. It does not change the fact that your answer is incorrect. There is no libcgmanager-dev or libcgmanager0 packages in any of the lxc PPAs. I've tried following your instructions and failed.

Comment: @InnocentBystander The answer reflected the current conditions when it was written. on Feb. 2nd. The missing file was included in the package mentioned. That's likely why it's the accepted answer. I'm sorry it didn't work for you and am glad you found a solution that did work for you.

Comment: @InnocentBystander If you have questions about how the site works, [Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) is a great resource. But the answer to your question regarding how/why answers are accepted can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/tour) "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

Comment: @ElderGeek, oh I get it. They must have removed those packages since then. Feel free to include the data from my answer in yours and I can just delete my answer. This way people will have up to date instructions.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I see no need to do that. The community will decide on the value of your answer and will vote accordingly. The highest rated answer isn't always the accepted one. And some questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau) never get an answer accepted.