# ubuntu 18.04 won't shutdown (freeze) after sleep

Tags: shutdown, 18.04, freeze, hibernate

Shutdown works fine, but when I come back from sleep mode, and I try to shutdown my computer, it simply freezes. The screen keeps showing my opened applications, but I can't do anything (no mouse or keyboard response). Finally, I have to force a shutdown pressing the power button.

Tried to edit grub file by adding `acpi=off` but had no success.

Edit:
path to grub file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

Edited that grub file by changing it from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off".
```

Also tried:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
```

but didn't work as well.

I'm using nvidia-driver-390. I'll see if this bug persists using the open source driver

My kernel is 4.16.8 (latest stable version)

Comment: Which grub file did you attempt to edit? Please help us help you by [edit]ing a copy into your post.

Comment: updated the post @ElderGeek. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after changing config file and reboot for changes to take effect?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, i did

Comment: If you've attempted numerous versions of the Nvidia driver, strange things can occur. [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau) might be useful to you.