# Error installing nvidia driver on 18.04 server

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried to install drivers, I have tried to clean apt and purge existing nivida driver, now I cannot uninstall any packages.

Here is error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: libnvidia-gl-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-dkms-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-driver-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-utils-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 410.48) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-410 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-410 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-410 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 331.20) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                          bumblebee but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libcuda1-410 but it is not installable
              Recommends: nvidia-opencl-icd-410 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And this error trying to fix unmeet dependencies: I have tired to remove/clear cache package.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-410 nvidia-compute-utils-410 nvidia-dkms-410 nvidia-driver-410
  nvidia-kernel-common-410 nvidia-kernel-source-410 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-410
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-410:i386 libnvidia-decode-410:i386 libnvidia-encode-410:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-410:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-410:i386 libnvidia-gl-410:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-410 nvidia-410-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-410 nvidia-compute-utils-410 nvidia-dkms-410 nvidia-driver-410
  nvidia-kernel-common-410 nvidia-kernel-source-410 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-410
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 205 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 166080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-390
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-410:amd64 (410.48-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/egl/egl_external_platform.d/10_nvidia_wayland.json', which is also in package nvidia-410 410.48-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-410_410.48-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481540/225694) useful.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/491086/915473 This "force-overwrite" option should help as well.