# My ubuntu 16.04 boot stuck at the logo

Tags: 16.04

I have used ubuntu 16.04 with two RTX1080 Ti for a month to do deep-learning, but yesterday I fond my Keras failed to run the program on GPU, so I change my driver to 430. But after I reboot it, the problem occurred. I can't get into tty mode, adding nomodeset also failed to launch, does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: In addition to `nomodeset` add `nosplash` and `noquiet` to have a better visibility of the kernel messages.

Comment: You might find [this useful](https://askubuntu.com/a/481540/225694)